# Did Tom Bombadil have a "prior art" in Norse/other mythology?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

We know that Tolkien heavily borrowed ideas from Norse and other mythologies, since Middle-Earth was meant to be the missing myths for England.

Was there a figure similar to Tom Bombadil in Norse or any other myths that Tolkien was using as basis for his work?

Similar meaning - old (oldest) creature, odd and somewhat OUTSIDE the normal pantheon, **deliberately** vague as to who and what it is. Impervious to supernatural evil (Tom is immune to the Ring) but doesn't fight it.

Please note that Tolkien apparently state that Tom!=Eru in the letters, so "top level world creator living in disguise" figures don't seem to match.

Answer (score 9):

Not that I'm aware of, but Tom was in origin not a part of the Middle-earth mythology.  Rather he was a character that existed already (originally published in the Oxford Magazine in 1933 or 34), and - in Tolkien's own words (Letter 153):

> In historical fact I put him in because I had already 'invented' him independently (he first appeared in the Oxford Magazine) and wanted an 'adventure' on the way.

Because of that I don't think it's valid to go looking for parallels to him in other mythologies, at least in the context of inspiration for Middle-earth.  Tom serves a different purpose in the story (Letter 153 again):

> I kept him in, and as he was, because he represents certain things otherwise left out.

And also (Letter 19):

> Tom Bombadil, the spirit of the (vanishing) Oxford and Berkshire countryside...

I'll leave the final words to the Professor himself (Letter 229):

> As for Wayland Smith being a Pan-type, or being reflected both in Bombadil and in Gollum: this is sufficient example of the silly methods and nonsensical conclusions of Dr. O. He is welcome to the rubbish, but I do not see that he, as a translator, has any right to unload it here.

Comment: "he represents certain things otherwise left out." - that seems to be something you can build on. What were those things? Were those things represented on other mythos?

Comment: Letter 144: "*he represents something that I feel important, though I would not be prepared to analyze the feeling precisely.*"